# How to make @Transient type in a @Model to update the UI when changed?

Tags: swift, swift-data

When we wrap a `@Model` with `@Transient`, it's outside scope of the SwiftData, but still i want the `@Transient` property to Update in the UI, when its value changes. Is it something by default in design of SwiftData or there are any work arounds. Here is my simplified code.

```swift
@Model
class Counter {
    var stored: Int = 0
    @Transient var notStored: Int = 0
    
    init(stored: Int, notStored: Int) {
        self.stored = stored
        self.notStored = notStored
    }
}
```

UI code

```swift
// Here cntrs is a list of @Query. When clicking on INC-STORED, it will 
// increment and show in the UI, but when click on INC-NON-STORED, its not showing up in the UI.
// So i want the @Model to behave as an @Observable, where the @Transient if not stored
// in db, at least trigger an UI update.
HStack {
    VStack {
        Text("\(cntrs[0].stored)")
        Button("INC-STORED") {
            cntrs[0].stored += 1
        }
    }
    VStack {
        Text("\(cntrs[0].notStored)")
        Button("INC-NON-STORED") {
            cntrs[0].notStored += 1
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
@Transient var notStored: Int = 0
```

to

```
@Attribute(.ephemeral) var notStored: Int = 0
```

and the UI will update properly. According to the documentation both should be used when a property shouldn't be persisted but only the second one clearly says it will track changes. I don't know if this difference is intentional or if `Transient` simply doesn't fully work yet.